# Runtime Analysis of Uniform Sampling via exact degree computation

Tags: runtime-analysis, randomized-algorithms

Let $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{B}$ given as a collection of arrays. The degree of an element $a \in \cup \mathcal{A}$, is the number of sets of $\mathcal{A}$ that it contains - that is, $d_{\mathcal{A}(x)} =|D_{\mathcal{A}}(x)|$, where $D_{\mathcal{A}} =\{A \in \mathcal{A} \mid a \in A\}$. The algorithms is as follows:

1. Pick one set (say $A$) from $\mathcal{A}$ with probability proportional to the their sizes.
2. Pick an element $a \in A$ uniformly at random.
3. Compute the degree of $d =d_{\mathcal{A}}(x)$.
4. Output a and stop with probability $1/d$.

**Question:** What will be the runtime of the algorithm?

**Edit:**

Let $N=|\cup \mathcal{A}|$ and $g =|\mathcal{A}|$ and $m=\sum_{X \in \mathcal{A}} |X|.$

Computing $d_{\mathcal{A}}(a)$ takes time $O(|\mathcal{A}|)$.

**Probability of success in any round? I am not getting this calculation.**

I want to calculate the runtime in terms of $N$, $g$ and $m$.

Comment: "that it contains" - do you mean that contains it?  What is $\mathcal{G}$?  How does it relate to $\mathcal{A}$?  What parameter do you want the runtime to be expressed in terms of?  What are your thoughts?  What progress have you made towards answering this question on your own?  What's the context where you encountered this question or this algorithm?   Please [edit] your question to address these issues.

Comment: Is there any significance to $\mathcal B$?

Comment: (For A, you sometimes use \mathcal, and sometimes not.)

Comment: @greybeard $A$ means set and $\mathcal{A}$ means collection of sets.

Comment: @greybeard $\mathcal{B}$ is a collection of sets from where $\mathcal{A}$ is drawn.